# How do I start another activity from UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException() method?

Tags: android, exception, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using global exception handling with “setUncaughtExceptionHandler” and “Toast”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171394/using-global-exception-handling-with-setuncaughtexceptionhandler-and-toast)

I have implemented `UncaughtExceptionHandler` in `onCreate()` in one of my activities.

In `uncaughtException()` method I am trying to open another activity `ErrorActivity` with an extra parameter (error msg and stacktrace). That activity should only show (ment globaly) `AlertDialog` and handle logs etc.

Can some one tell me why the `ErrorActivity` doesnt open while the code in `oncoughtException` gets executed? I suspect the problem is `Thread` related.

Here is my first activity (simulating exception in `onCreate()`)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GlobalSettings settings;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
                new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                               ErrorActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent); 
            } 
        } );

        settings = (GlobalSettings) getApplication();
        settings = null;
        settings.getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

And my second activity that should handle errors:

```
public class ErrorActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = bundle.getString("ERROR");
        ShowAlertDialog(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you got any error or force fully close the application please provide here logcat detail and your AndroidManifest file

Comment: the AndroidManifest file is ok. Activity is registered there ok. No error happens. After startActivity() is called nothing happens (blank screen). LogCat is clean.

Comment: I suggest you to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and singleTask in Intent

Comment: Saurabh can you please provide example of the line?

Comment: ex. intent.setFlag(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) put before start new Activity

Comment: @Pratik i tried adding (     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);) before starting activity and nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [Using global exception handling with “setUncaughtExceptionHandler” and “Toast”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171394/using-global-exception-handling-with-setuncaughtexceptionhandler-and-toast/3171980#3171980)

There Qberticus told

> You're not seeing anything because the
>   exception happened on your UI thread
>   and the stack unrolled all the way. So
>   there is no more Looper and there is
>   no support there that is used to
>   display the Toast.

Since the exception happens on UI we cannot do an UI operation :(

Comment: i have also tried calling the activity in a new thread. It is not working.

Comment: new thread will not work. You need to start new `task`. I don't know how, since the flag _FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK_ is not working

Comment: probably new process, but im not sure if that is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can add attribute `android:process=":report_process"` to the `<activity>` element which refers to your bug report activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

By default, activities belong to the same appliction would run in the same process identified by your package name.  By setting `android:process` attribute, you can override this.  `android:process` starting with `:` refers to a private identifier within your package, so that you can start the activity in a new process without conflicting other packages' process.