# Android Remove notification when activity destroyed or App crashed

Tags: android, notifications

When my app crashes for any reason `onDestroy()` method is not called. My notification is also not removed. Where should `notifi.cancel(1);` method be called to remove the notification whenever the app crashes?

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (nm != null) {
        nm.cancel(0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `onDestroy()` is not called when the app is crashed. To get a callback before the app is crashed, you should use an Exception Handler as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171394/using-global-exception-handling-with-setuncaughtexceptionhandler-and-toast). You should write the code for removing the notification in an Exception Handler.

```
Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();  
                    // Cancel Notification
                    if (nm != null) {
                        nm.cancel(0);
                    }
                    Looper.loop();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

Also you might want to take a look at this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028742/how-to-clear-a-notification-if-activity-crashes).

Answer (score 0):

`onDestory()` method is called when system is low memory or when you call `finish()` method. So when your app crashed, will not call `onDestory()` method. 
[check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) [check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called)

> where is best position for run notifi.cancel(1); method?

You can call any where `notifi.cancel(1);`. This all demand on what is needed.

Comment: if app crashed, How do I cancel notifications?

Comment: The question asked is about the place to call the `notifi.cancel(1)` method when the app crashes, and your answer is incorrect. You cannot just call it anywhere. Its supposed to be called only when the app crashes.

Comment: app crash is cause by exception when not handled and it is not good thing. you should catch the exception and you can call in catch block notifi.cancel(1)

Comment: _Everything crashes, even Google applications do._ http://stackoverflow.com/a/4598457/451951